# 3D matrix multiplication by 2D matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a NxNx4 matrix(`A`) and a 4x4 matrix (`B`). I need to multiply the vector `a` composed by the four elements of the first matrix `A`, let's say

```
a = A(1,1,1) 
    A(1,1,2)
    A(1,1,3)
    A(1,1,4)
```

by the 4x4 matrix `B` but I'm not sure if there is a faster and clever solution than using a `for` loop to build the vector `a`. Does exist a way to do this computation with few lines of code?

I built `A` like

```
A(:,:,1) = rand(20);
A(:,:,2) = rand(20);
A(:,:,3) = rand(20);
A(:,:,4) = rand(20);
```

and the matrix `B`

```
B = rand(4);
```

now I want to multiply `B` with

```
B*[A(1,1,1);A(1,1,2);A(1,1,3);A(1,1,4)]
```

This, for each element of A

```
B*[A(1,2,1);A(1,2,2);A(1,2,3);A(1,2,4)]
B*[A(1,3,1);A(1,3,2);A(1,3,3);A(1,3,4)]
...
```

Comment: You describe having an `N*N*4` matrix, and a `4*4` matrix, and your example `a` is neither! Please show a [mcve] of your expected input / output, this sounds relatively easy if it were well defined, but at present it's unclear.

Comment: How does it look now?

Comment: That's a lot clearer, my only other question will be what your expected output is? Each multiplication yields a `4*1` vector, I guess your expected output `C` is a matrix the same size as `A`?

Comment: That's right. `C` is supposed to be again an NxNx4 matrix. I'm choosing the multidimensional matrix instead of 4 separate matrix to be able to compute the classical multiplication matrix-vector `B*a`

Comment: I'm not entirely sure based on your explanation if you simply need `bsxfun(@times, ...)` or something more advanced like [`mmx`](https://github.com/yuvaltassa/mmx) or [`mtimesx`](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25977).

Comment: I cannot use `mtimesx` because `A` and `B` are complex and the help says it works with single and double. `mmx` I'm not sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a simple loop, note [loops aren't necessarily slow](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/02/12/run-code-faster-with-the-new-matlab-execution-engine/) in newer MATLAB versions. Mileage may vary.

Loops have the advantage of improving code readability, it's extremely clear what's happening here:

```
% For matrix A of size N*N*4
C = zeros( size( A ) );
for ii = 1:N
    for jj = 1:N
        C( ii, jj, : ) = B * reshape( A( ii, jj, : ), [], 1 );
    end
end
```

Comment: Mmm and you can confirm me that this is doing what I need, right? I was expecting  two zero matrices out of four (the ones of the third index)

Comment: As in Luis answer, `C(m,n,:)` is the same as `B*[A(m,n,1);A(m,n,2);A(m,n,3);A(m,n,4)];` for any `m` and `n` - you should be able to confirm this yourself quite easily?

Answer (score 1):

A loop solution that has good performance specially when N is large:

```
s = size(A, 3);
C = A(:,:,1) .* reshape(B(:,1),1,1,[]);
for k = 2:s
    C = C + A(:,:,k) .* reshape(B(:,k),1,1,[]);
end
```

Comment: This is *very* quick relative to my suggestion for `N >> B`. I like the step back you've taken to use the definition of `B*x` to take advantage of the shorter loop. For `N = 1000, B = 4` I find this ~30x quicker.

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want:

```
C = permute(sum(bsxfun(@times, permute(B, [3 4 2 1]), A), 3), [1 2 4 3]);
```

Check:

```
>> C(1,2,:)
ans(:,:,1) =
   1.501739582138850
ans(:,:,2) =
   1.399465238902816
ans(:,:,3) =
   0.715531734553844
ans(:,:,4) =
   1.617019921519029
>> B*[A(1,2,1);A(1,2,2);A(1,2,3);A(1,2,4)]
ans =
   1.501739582138850
   1.399465238902816
   0.715531734553844
   1.617019921519029
```